# Faster way in Xcode to archive, validate, and upload multiple targets to the app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8

I have an Xcode project with multiple targets.  Everytime I push a new build to the app store I have to archive, validate, and upload each target separately, which is very time consuming.  Is there a tool or script that can automate this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools). I have used it for two years now and it saves me time every day.
You could give it a try.